# Got an error message: error: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java

First I have a class and the class has a void method:

```java
class IntGroup {
    int size;
    List<int[]> intervals;
    
    public IntGroup() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    }
        
    public void addInt(int[] interval) {
        this.intervals.add(interval);
        this.size++;
    }
}
```

Then when I try to create a List, create a new object and call the method

```java
// int[][] intervals
List<IntGroup> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new IntGroup().addInt(intervals[0]));
```

I got error message `error: 'void' type not allowed here list.add(new IntGroup().addInt(intervals[0]));`. I tried to change the return type of `addInt` to `List` and `int`, neither worked.

Comment: You're calling `list.add` with the return value of `addInt`... but `addInt` doesn't return anything. What do you expect to be added to the list?

Answer (score 7):

You're calling `list.add` with "whatever is returned from the `addInt` method"... but the `addInt` method is declared with a `void` return type... it doesn't return anything, so you can't use the return value.

Two options to fix this:

**1) Change `addInt` to return `IntGroup`:**

```java
public IntGroup addInt(int[] interval) {
    this.intervals.add(interval);
    this.size++;
    return this;
}
```

At this point, the existing `list.add` call is valid, because `addInt` returns an `IntGroup` - the same reference it was called on.

This is a reasonably common pattern in some APIs, such as `StringBuilder`, but it's not clear that it's appropriate here.

**2) Separate out the `list.add` call from the `addInt` call**

Just use a local variable to "remember" the group you're working with:

```java
IntGroup group = new IntGroup();
group.add(intervals[0]);
list.add(group);
```

Comment: Both worked. I thought the return type of `list.add()` and `addInt()` should be the same, now I understand the content in the parenthesis of `list.add()` has to be the same type as in the angle brackets (`List<IntGroup>`).

Answer (score 2):

`addInt` Returns void and you try to add it to the list:

```
new IntGroup().addInt(intervals[0]); <-- this is a void because addInt returns void
```

Try this instead:

```java
// int[][] intervals
List<IntGroup> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntGroup intGroup = new IntGroup();
intGroup.addInt(intervals[0]);
list.add(intGroup);
```